# Not getting alias in select function in Yii2 from result of query response

Tags: php, yii2

My code is below. Issue is that when i have print_r the $data then i am not getting the total_points.

```
$query = IdsAwardEntries::find()
                ->select(['ids_award_entries.*','SUM(ids_award_points.i_award_points) AS total_points']) 
                ->join('LEFT JOIN', IdsAwardPoints::tableName(), 'ids_award_points.ids_award_entry_id=ids_award_entries.id')
                ->where([
                    'ids_award_entries.deleted_at' => null,
                    'ids_award_entries.i_shortlist_status' => 1,
                ])
                ->groupBy('ids_award_entries.id')
                ->all()
                ;
```

Please help me where i am wrong. How can i extract total_points value from the response?

Also For your information, i am getting response without the error. When i apply sorting function on total_points then it's working very well according ASC and DESC order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an ActiveModel    IdsAwardEntries  and in this case show only the data related to activeModel  ..

if you want see also  the total_points alias  for sum a simple way is add  this name as a public var in the IdsAwardEntries model

```
class IdsAwardEntries extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $total_points;  
    .....
```